# Textfield not printing formatted

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, jstl, textfield

I have a textfield being populated with data from the database, and the issue here is when the users update this field. They add a new line when editing, but when I print it, it's all in just one line, see  below:

What is the best solution to easily update this field and print it friendly?

Here is the user editing the textfield:

[image: Here is the user editing the textfield]

Here is printing it, see? Not formatted:

[image: and here is I'm printing it. I would like it as image 1]

Hope I was clear here. Sorry if not. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view the source of the "display page", you will see that it does indeed include the newlines, however the HTML presentation masks them.

One suggestion is to wrap the output in a `pre` tag. This will cause the output to be displayed exactly as the user entered it, spaces and all:

```
<pre><c:out value="${row.currentStatus}" /></pre>
```

Another suggestion is to use CSS to accomplish the same as above  [[JSFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/VwGSf/):

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Another suggestion is to replace the newlines with breaks as follows:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("linefeed", "\n"); %> 
<c:out value="${fn:replace(row.currentStatus, linefeed, "<br />")}" escapeXml="false" />
```

Optionally do this third suggestion in your controller to avoid specifying `escapeXml="false"` which could be a security concern.

Comment: Hey I used this one and have no words to say how it helped me sir! Thank you so much!!!

<% pageContext.setAttribute("linefeed", "\n"); %> 
<c:out value="${fn:replace(row.currentStatus, linefeed, "<br />")}" escapeXml="false" />

Answer (score 0):

replace new line to break

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />");
```